# How to remove from few tables if data exist in each table?

Tags: mysql

I have 7 tables
i need to remove data from all, but sometimes i don't have data in one of tables so the regular DELETE not working(return false)

```
DELETE `lead`.*, `wp_users`.*, `wp_sfmembers`.*, `wp_usermeta`.*,
       `crm_notes`.*,`deposits`.*,`meta_accounts`.* 
FROM `lead`, `wp_users`, `wp_sfmembers`,
     `wp_usermeta`, `crm_notes`,
     `deposits`, `meta_accounts` 
WHERE
  `wp_users`.`ID`=`lead`.`uid` 
  AND `wp_sfmembers`.`user_id`=`lead`.`uid` 
  AND `wp_usermeta`.`user_id`=`lead`.`uid` 
  AND `crm_notes`.`uid`=`lead`.`id` 
  AND `deposits`.`uid`=`lead`.`id` 
  AND `meta_accounts`.`uid`=`lead`.`id` 
  AND `lead`.`id`='89'
```

I tried to do with JOIN but it deletes me wrong data:

```
DELETE `l`.*
FROM `lead` as `l`   
     LEFT OUTER  JOIN `wp_users` ON `wp_users`.`ID`=`l`.`uid`
     LEFT OUTER  JOIN `wp_sfmembers` ON `wp_sfmembers`.`user_id`=`l`.`uid`
     LEFT OUTER  JOIN `wp_usermeta` ON `wp_usermeta`.`user_id`=`l`.`uid` 
     LEFT OUTER  JOIN `crm_notes` ON `crm_notes`.`uid`=`l`.`uid` 
     LEFT OUTER  JOIN `deposits` ON `deposits`.`uid`=`l`.`id` 
     LEFT OUTER  JOIN `meta_accounts` ON `meta_accounts`.`uid`=`l`.`id`
     AND `l`.`id`='89'
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `AND l.id=89` be `WHERE l.id=89`?

Answer (score 2):

Just run 7 separate delete queries instead of one complex one.
That's rule of the thumb: if you can't do something complex way - do it easy way. Easy ways always works.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but deleting correlated data between multiple tables would be a pain when done in isolation.